# Render different controller methods as JSON in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I have a resource that renders as JSON perfectly fine at `localhost:3000/gins.json` from `@gins = Gin.order(name: :desc)`.

Which will return ALL `gins`.  However, I'd like to have a JSON response that only returns the last 4 gins, to use elsewhere. In the controller I also have:

`@latestgins = Gin.order("created_at DESC").first(4)`

The above would work in an index.html.erb view with `<%= @latestgins.name %>`, but how do I get the JSON for this? I have tried `render json: @latestgins` but navigating to `localhost:3000/latestings.json`, of course, gives a routing error.

I suspect I'm attacking this in completely the wrong way, but only just starting out with Rails API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add respond to format json in your index method:

```
def index
  @gins = Gin.order(name: :desc)
  @latestgins = Gin.order("created_at DESC").first(4)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @latestgins }
  end
end
```

your `@latestgins` is now available here : `localhost:3000/gins.json`

---

#### Edit

If you want a custom route to display your data, just add it in your routes:

```
defaults format: :json do
  get 'last4gins', to: "gins#index"
end
```

Your data for the last 4 entries is available at `http://localhost:3000/last4gins.json`, at `http://localhost:3000/last4gins` but also at `localhost:3000/gins.json`

If you want to keep the `gins` index route clean, you can also create a custom method and remove the `@latestgins` from your index:

```
# routes
get 'last4gins', to: "gins#last4gins"

#controller
def index
  @gins = Gin.order(name: :desc)
end

def last4gins
  @latestgins = Gin.order("created_at DESC").first(4)
  render json: @latestgins
end
```

Now the data is no more available at `/gins.json`

Comment: Thanks @sovalina.  I can already access `localhost:3000/gins.json` (just updated the post to make that more clear). How would I also access something like `localhost:3000/last4gins.json`?

Comment: Thanks that's worked.  I've taken the route of adding the custom method.  Now I've learnt this technique, it opens a lot of other things for me.  Thanks,